# How can i grab specific string inside the brackets

Tags: python

I am new in python, how can i grab specific string inside `[]` only, without other thing? Here is the string

```
Opening /root/pact-01.cap    Nan
Name: [8;28TH[KEY FOUND! [ string ][11, type: object
```

I only want a specific string `[ string ]` , how can i filter all other things and `[]` and get the string.

Comment: With our without the square brackets?

Comment: without the square brackets.

Comment: Look into "regular expressions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex to match the contents.

```
\[([^[]*)\]
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/KcEIWr/1)

*There is an explanation to how the regex works on the live demo.*

In Python it would look like:

```
import re

s = """
Opening /root/pact-01.cap    Nan
Name: [8;28TH[KEY FOUND! [ string ][11, type: object
"""

for match in re.finditer(r"\[([^[]*)\]", s):
    print(match.group(1))
```

That would print:

```
 string
```

To just find a single match, you can do:

```
match = re.search(r"\[([^[]*)\]", s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

The if statement tells whether there was a match since `match` is `None` in the case of no matches.

Comment: You're welcome. Regex can definitely take some getting used to, but in the end it has so many uses even outside the world of programming.